# store date in sqlite3 table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database with a datetime field, the format of the date/time im trying to store is 2012-01-01 07:15:00, though the database returns it as 2012-24-01T07:00:00+00:00,
what is the best method do fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using `DateTime.parse(schedule.time)` to store the date and convert it around

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the current time to a timestamp:

```
Date.new(YYYY,MM,DD).to_time.to_i
```

Store this timestamp to the database.

Retrieve the timestamp and try converting:

```
Time.at(TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Try DateTime.new(YYYY, MM, DD, H, M, S). 
The unix timestamp is just the amount of seconds passed since Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

Comment: i have been able to use it in my controller, though its having with the - put within the date, NoMethodError in SchedulesController#update

`undefined method '-' for "24-06-2012 12:02 pm":String`